# Using viewmodelScope launch with lifecycle transformations

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I am using the following versions in my project -

```
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0-alpha04"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.2.0-alpha04"
```

So in my View Model class, I do -

```
fun initView() =
        Transformations.map(domain.performOperation()) {
            when (it) {
                ...
            }
        }
```

My View Model class extends Base View Model class and the Base View Model class looks like this -

```
open class BaseViewModel(private val coroutineCtx: CoroutineContext = Dispatchers.Main) :
    ViewModel(),
    CoroutineScope {

    private val job = SupervisorJob()

    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = coroutineCtx + job

    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        job.cancel()
    }
}
```

This seems to work but I want to improvise my code and get rid of the boilerplate coroutine code in Base View Model class. So I want to use `viewModelScope.launch` directly in My View Model class. But how do I use it with `Transformations.map`?

Comment: Did you check the documentation here https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines ?

Comment: @MrVasilev Yes but there is no mention of how to use it with Transformations.map

Comment: Are you sure you need Transformations.map? What is your scenario and what you want to achieve? Could you share more of your code?

Comment: @MrVasilev Yes I use Transformations.map because my domain returns me a sealed class of APIResult which I map to ViewState in the ViewModel class and give it to the view

Comment: So, if I understand correct your 'domain' contains your business logic and do a REST call to some Server and returns a LiveData<APIResult> and after based on this result you update your View, right?

Comment: Yes exactly....

Answer (score 0):

So, if I got everything correct maybe solution like this can help you:

In you Activity/Fragment

```
lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {
        val apiResult = viewModel.initView()
        updateUI(apiResult)
        }
```

In your ViewModel

```
private val apiDeferred = CompletableDeferred<LiveData<APIResult>>()

suspend fun initView(): LiveData<APIResult> {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val apiResult = domain.performOperation()
            artsDeferred.complete(arts)
        }
        return apiDeferred.await()
    }
```

And you can also check this video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BOHK_w09pVA&t=1230s (after 22th min)

Please, say if this works for you or no, I also can suggest another solutions with the newest tech coroutines, liveData and so on

Comment: Yes it works but I wanted more with Transformations.map